# How do I do a search from Windows Explorer for numbers in filename?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

I am on Windows 10 and I am trying to do a search on a directory in Windows Explorer. So I go up to the search box in the upper right and type in `959` to try to pull up any file in the folder with the string '959' in the filename.

But nothing comes up though I know for a fact there is one (because I am looking right at it), I even try `*959*` and I still get no hits.

Using the standard Windows Explorer search box in the upper right, how DO I do a search for a filename containing a specific string of numbers?

Again, not trying to search contents even, just the filenames.

Comment: It sounds like the folder is not indexed, or you need to rebuild your index. Type `indexing options` from Start to find the area to do this.

Comment: It may already be indexed, because I *can* search and find in the folder for text based searches, like "name" or "doc" - it's only when I use digits like "959" that the search fails.

Comment: And I just checked, the folder in question is my Downloads folder, and it IS already indexed.

Comment: Ah, okay. +1. Make sure you are not using the quotes around the numbers. You should just be typing the numbers alone

Comment: Correct, I am not using quotes.

Comment: I experimented on my W10 pc, it seems if the numbers are separated from letters it will find it when I search for 959, example i made a new file "old-959-new.txt", it finds it but if I modify it to "old_kb959-new.txt" it does not, weird. In windows 7 it did the same thing but but on the second search of the renamed file, search prompted me (yellow drop down banner) to add that particular folder to be indexed, so I did, then it showed up in the search.

Comment: That parallels my experience - maybe it's just a bug with no fix? (Apart from renaming all one's file, of course.)

Comment: Thanks for digging this up Sindyr, what you are seeing is a bug in how the Windows indexer is handling wildcard queries. It will be fixed in the Windows Fall Creators Update. Until then, the best workaround would be to include the text as a prefix if it is possible

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to search multiple folders for a number in a file name, but you must use the entire number. (No need for any alphabetical characters.)

When you run a search, Windows Explorer displays a `Search Tools` tab at the top of the window. Under the `Refine` section, you can click on a drop down menu `Other properties` and then select `Name`. Now type in the number that you are looking for within the file name and it will display the file in the search results.  See the screenshot below.

You can also just type `name:` in the search bar as a prefix to the number. For example, if you are looking for a file with the number `00385522` in its name, type `name:00385522` in the search bar.

[image: Screenshot]